# Upload images/files through google drive API

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, google-drive-api, google-cloud-platform

The web app I'm working on angular web app that needs to allow user to upload images and PDF files when they want to register an account in our system. What I want to achieve is to have a button in the page, once clicked, the user can browse the images or files they need to upload, and then the code will call api to store the images or files in google drive. These images or files will then be shown in another page for admin to review and approve.

I'm using a VM from Google Cloud to host the system, and I enabled the Google Drive api form the Google Cloud console, but I got stuck on the authorization part (I have referred the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/simple-upload ). I was confused with where to get the auth token, I had the api key generated from the Google Cloud console, but I don't see anything about auth token in Google Cloud console.

I do not wish to let the user to sign in to their google account when they need to upload something, using google drive should be transparent to the user. All the images and files uploaded to the Google Drive should be public and open for all for read-only access, and partial write access (only allowed to add new files, cannot delete or overwrite existing files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want the user to sign-in his Google account, the remaining option for you would be to use [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount) in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with Google Drive, however, maybe you can find some information in this documentation page about [Authorizing Google Drive requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing).

In any case, given the use case that you explained in the question, and as I understand that you are just starting with the development, let me suggest the usage of [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) (a product of the Google Cloud Platform just like the Compute Engine instance that you are using to host your application), instead of Google Drive.

Google Drive's main aim is providing file storage for end users, while Google Cloud Storage's primarily focus are app developers and backend system storage. Some of the main advantages of using Cloud Storage over Google Drive as the storing system for your application are:

- Flexible usage-based [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing-summary/). More detailed info in the specific [pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).
- Fully integrated with other products in the Platform (like Compute Engine instances). You can make use of the [different available APIs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis) to access it, although I would recommend the idiomatic Client Library for your preferred language. However, if you are using Angular, you may be instead interested in the [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/).
- API designed for unlimited scale and offering an [enterprise-grade SLA](https://cloud.google.com/storage/sla) (unlike Drive, which does not have SLA for its API).

Finally, getting back to the topic of authorization, you can have a look at [this other documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing). Also, regarding the access control of the objects stored in Cloud Storage, you can have a look at [how to manage access control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).

I know this answer does not exactly offer the solution you want for authorizing requests in Google Drive API, but I think that for your use case, Cloud Storage is a better fit, so it is worth having a look at it.

Comment: thanks. We just thought that google drive solution might be cheaper than google storage. Since images may easily grow in short time.